# MySQL Update Field Where Time is more than Specified in Specific Day

Tags: mysql, time-format, str-to-date

I have database table and I want to update some fields where the time is more than 17:15:59 and the day is not Friday

I've made the schema in sqlfiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8e99/1

And this is the query:

```
UPDATE saring SET pulang = '12:00:59'
WHERE TIME_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(pulang, '%r'), '%T') > '17:15:59' AND DAYNAME(STR_TO_DATE(tanggal, '%a')) != 'Friday'
```

But I am definitely doing something wrong. I need some help.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change the columns types into this:

```
tanggal: date
pulang: time
```

And change the dates format into something likde: '2015-08-10'.
This enables you to run query without the Timeformat function like this:

```
UPDATE saring SET pulang = '12:00:59'
WHERE pulang > '17:15:59' 
AND DAYNAME(tanggal) != 'Friday'
```

The page you made, doesn't seem to update queries, so try this on your localhost server. Here Is a sqlfiddle with SELECT statement:
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1337/1)

Comment: thanks, finally i follow your idea to change the columns type and i got it working